# Who was the Megilat Esther?

Tags: sources-mekorot, history, commentaries, biography

As in the commentary on the Rambam’s Sefer HaMitzvot. Do we know this person’s identity? Or even when this person lived?

Answer (score 7):

[R. David Conforte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Conforte) identifies  ([Korei Hadorot 28a](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7419&st=&pgnum=62&hilite=)) the author of Megillat Esther as [R. Isaac de Leon](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%97%D7%A7_%D7%93%D7%99_%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%90%D7%95%D7%9F), a student of R. Isaac Kampaton. [R. Hayyim Joseph David Azulai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaim_Yosef_David_Azulai), however, ([Shem Hagedolim Vol. I](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Sifre_shem_ha_gedolim/I3AFd_UbJcsC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=shem%20ha%20gedolim&printsec=frontcover) entry 333 for the letter Yod) raised several arguments against this identification and concluded that the author of Megillat Esther was [R. Isaac Leon](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php/%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99_%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%97%D7%A7_%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%90%D7%95%D7%9F) (where Leon was his name rather than his city of origin) the author of a halachic work printed in Rome in 1547.